# Optimization problem

Tags: functions

Suppose that I have a big pipe and I want to put n small pipes in it, say 8 pipes 1 inch each. What is the smallest radius for the biggest pipe to contain all of the small ones? Constraint minimization, they must not be inside one another. How will I write the function, which will minimize this radius for the general case for a general n? [image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I need to write an algorithm for n number of circles, when I change the n number the amount of the small circles will change and the radius of the biggest circle will change too.

Comment: If you want to add more details to your question then you should edit the question and add them to the question body. You shouldn't clarify your question or add extra details as an answer. Answers are only for--well--answers.